# C# object - create reference from text

Tags: c#

I have a c# object called Client.  It has a few properties, let's use ClientID as the example.

Client.ClientID

I have another object called ChildNode.  It has a few properties too, one of which is ChildNodeName.

ChildNodeName corresponds to the names used in the client properties :

ChildNode.ChildNodeName = "ClientID"

I'd like to loop through the ChildNodeNames and set the corresponding property value in the Client object.

Is there a way I can use the text from ChildNodeName (ie ClientID) to access the property of the Client object (ie Client.ClientID)?

Comment: The term you may be looking for is "reflection".

Comment: `client.GetType().GetProperty(childNodeName).SetValue(client, newValue)`

Comment: It would be really great if you posted real code with real data and a real explanation of what you need to do. Otherwise, you're asking us to write real code for you to give you an answer - and then our real code won't match your real code and it'll be a PITA for everyone.

Comment: David, John - thank you.  Exactly what I was after.

Enigmativity - I would have posted code, but there wasn't any as I didn't know what I was looking for.  Thanks for the advice though.